# Creating a class which calculates the third derivate

Tags: python, list, loops, class, plot

I'm currently working on a task where I have to create a class which calculates the third derivate. In this case the third derivate is formulated like this:

https://gyazo.com/cc4d6d9bb152c6f6583179ad4ffab09d

To test the class I have to use the function:

f(x) = cos (x)

The third derivate of this function should be:

f'''(x) = sin(x)

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
from math import *
def f(x):
    return cos(x)

class Third_derivate:
    def __init__ (self, f, h):
        self.f = f
        self.h = h
        
    def __call__ (self, x):
        
        f = self.f
        h = self.h
        
        return (- 0.5 *f*(x - 2*h) + f(x - h) - f(x - h)  + 0.5 * f(x + 2*h)) / h**3
    
def test():
    f = lambda x: a*x + b
    a = 5
    b = 10
    dfdx = Third_derivate(f, h = 0.5)
    diff = abs(dfdx(4.5) - a)
    assert diff < 1E-14, 'class has a fault, diff = %s' % diff
    
df = Third_derivate(cos, 1E-7)
x = 1
print(df(x))
```

The error code I get is:

```
 return (- 0.5 *f*(x - 2*h) + f(x - h) - f(x - h)  + 0.5 * f(x + 2*h)) / h**3

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `f*(x - 2*h)` instead of `f(x - 2*h)`.  I think you got it right the second time.